# How to make multiplication with subquery in addSelect in QueryBuilder

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, dql

I use Doctrine2 and QueryBuilder. I need to have expression like (select oneval from Abb\Entity\Table)*sometable.amount/exchange

```
$qb=$this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->addSelect('p.amount*(select crr.rateusd from
Application\DBUtils\Entities\Currency 
where crr.code=c.currency)/25 as amountselected');
```

**[Syntax Error] line 0, col 241: Error: Expected Literal, got 'select'**

thank you

Comment: Did you find a proper solution @Konstantin Vahrushev?

Comment: @webDEVILopers
I had to replace subquery with join. So as a result I had:
**$qb->addSelect('p.amount*curr.rateusd as amountselected')
->leftJoin('Application\DBUtils\Entities\Currency', 'curr', \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join::WITH, 'c.currency = curr.code')
     ->leftJoin('Application\DBUtils\Entities\Customer', 'c', \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join::WITH, 'p.customerid = c.id');**

Answer (score 0):

For such things i would use a native query.
[Doctrine Docs - Native Query](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.1/reference/native-sql.html)